# Why this search can not generate correct result?

Tags: delphi

Below is to find same customer and if he is in list, the number add one. If he is not in the list, just add him in the list.

I use Search function to do this, but failed and generated incorrect records. It can not find the customer or the right number of customers. 
But if I use For..loop to iterate the list, it does well and can find the customer and add new customer in that for..loop search procedure. (I did not paste for ..loop search procedrue here).

Another problem is that there is no difference between setting list.sorted true and false. It seems Search function is not correct. This search function is from an example of delphi textbook.

The below is with Delphi 7.

Thank you.

```
Procedure Form1.create;
begin
list:=Tstringlist.create;
list.sorted:=true;  // Search function will generate exactly Same and Incorrect 
                    //records no matter list.sorted is set true or false. 
//list.duplicates:=dupignore;

end;

Procedure addcustomer;
var
customer: string;
    begin
    //... Here is the code part that P1 is created as regular expression (omitted)
    while p1.MatchAgain do begin //p1 is regular expression
    customer:=p1.MatchedExpression; // try to match customer name.
    if (search(customer)=false) then begin //this line output wrong number
   // if (forloopsearch(customer)=false) then begin // this forloopsearch is ok
    list.Add(customer+'=1');
    end;
    allcustomer:=allcustomer+1; // global allcustomer is integer to count all customers

    end;


Function Tform1.search(customer: string): boolean;
var
 fre:string;
 num:integer;
 L:integer;
 R:integer;
 M: Integer;
 CompareResult: Integer;
 found: boolean;
begin
result:=false;
found:=false;
L := 0;
R := List.Count - 1;
while (L <= R) and ( not found ) do
begin
    M := (L + R) div 2;
    CompareResult := Comparetext(list.Names[m]), customer);
    if (compareresult=0) then
    begin
      fre:=list.ValueFromIndex [m];
      num:=strtoint(fre);
      num:=num+1;
      list.ValueFromIndex[m]:=inttostr(num);
      Found  := True;
      Result := true;
      exit;
      end
    else if compareresult > 0 then
      r := m - 1
    else
      l := m + 1;
  end;

end;
```

Edit:

Thank you all.

In order to clarify the problem, I copy the test code from my computer here and I am sorry for my redundancy.

Below is the name file that contains 3 persons' names (totally, 45 johns, 45 maries, and 45 erics).

```
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
mary, mary, mary, john, john, john, eric, eric, eric,
```

The forloopsearch will generate the following. Below is a copy result that reads key and value and add into a listview (using add method of listview. items). This result is correct and is what I want.

```
  mary  45
  john  45
  eric  45
```

Below is forloopsearch.

```
Function Tform1.forloopsearch(customer: string): boolean;
var
 fre:string;
 i: integer;
aname:string;
 num:integer;
begin
result:=false;
for i:=0 to list.count-1 do begin
  aname:=list.names[i];
  if aname=customer then
      begin
      fre:=list.ValueFromIndex [i];
      num:=strtoint(fre);
      num:=num+1;
      list.ValueFromIndex[i]:=inttostr(num);
      Result := true;
      End;
 end;
end;
```

The forloopsearch function output above is correct and it modifies values of keys in iteration.

The Search function will output the following. It is not correct and is not what I want. It also modifies values of keys in loop, but output is obviously wrong.

In both cases, list.sorted is set true when form is created as shown above. They both use same procedure to iterate the list and copy key and value in order into a listview (by using add method). Below is Search function result.

```
mary    3   
john    2   
john    1   
eric    1   
eric    4   
eric    40
mary    3   
john    1   
john    40
john    1   
mary    39
```

How to solve it. Thank you again.

Comment: Your code with '..' lines cannot be compiled.

Comment: You've got a binary search there, AFAICS there's nothing wrong with it, and the list has got to be sorted for it to work. But the list cannot be sorted if you are to modify the 'Value' of a name-value pair. Probably you're going to delete and re-add the entry. As for the error, are you sure you're passing a correct customer name to the search function.

Comment: What results did you expect, and what results did you see instead? Give us an example input, and show how your expected output differs form the actual output you observe.

Comment: Thank you Rob and Sertac Akyuz, Please look at my edition. How can I solve it?

Comment: @user - Is the stringlist sorted with the search function? How can you have that output with a sorted list?

Comment: Thank you  Sertac. I output the list after Search function to listview and reorder listview in frequency. The problem is why there are other johns in the list. I expect there is only one john (key) in the list and the total occurrences(number) of john is in Value as forloopsearch does. The forloopsearch and Search function are through same procedure that move data from list to listview. The forsearch and Search function use the same list that is set sorted=true when it is created.

Comment: I do not think the list is sorted. list.ValueFromIndex[m]:=inttostr(num);
will give you an exception if it was.

Comment: Thank you Mikael again. Can you please look at the wrong result above and let me know why and how to solve it.

Comment: @user - Add this to the very beginning of the search function: `Assert(list.Sorted);`, and see if the assertion fails or not.

Comment: Thank you Sertac for your response. If I add Assert(list.sorted) there and run, it prompts: ..raised exception class EAssertionFailed with message " Assertion Failure". Are there other ways?

Comment: @user - It means the list is **not** sorted. You've got to have the stringlist sorted for a binary search to work.

Comment: Thank you Sertac. Does it mean list.sorted:=true is not working ? How can I make it a sorted list?

Comment: @user - (1) No, I can't imagine it not working. There's got to be sth. else. Maybe you have more than one list, or at some point the code is setting 'sorted' to false. (2) You can sort an usorted list by calling its sort method: `list.Sort`.

Comment: Thank you  Sertac very much. Please look at my new edition. Your first comment should be marked as answer.

Comment: @user - You're welcome. But you shouldn't be changing questions on the fly, instead consider asking a new one based on where the progress is heading you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The question initially was a failing binary search on a `StringList`, and the reason turned out to be that the list was not sorted while the search was executed. See comments on the question.)

---

What I would do would be to keep the stringlist sorted at all times, and instead of a 'Name=Value' pair to keep the frequency of occurrence, use the [`Objects`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStrings_Objects.html) property for that. This would help avoid the Integer<->String conversion the code originally had and can be achieved with sth like: `list.Objects[i] := Pointer(f + 1);`

Use the stringlist's [`Find`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStringList_Find.html) method to find out if an entry already existed or not. `Find` executes a binary search itself, you don't need 3rd party code to do that. If the item exists already, just increment the frequency. If the item does not exist, the `Index` parameter that is set by the function is the place where the item should be inserted (see the documentation link above). Call the protected method `InsertItem` to insert the new item. The reason for the *protected* call is to avoid the find method run again needlessly (see `TStringList.AddObject` function in 'classes.pas'). This would be achieved with sth. like:

```
type
  TSL = class(TStringList);

var
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'Joe';
  if list.Find(s, i) then
    list.Objects[i] := Pointer(Integer(list.Objects[i]) + 1)
  else
    TSL(list).InsertItem(i, s, Pointer(1));
end;
```

But you really need to profile and test alternatives, otherwise it is all based on guesswork.

**edit:** I would like to note that if there's no adding/deleting items outside of this procedure, the stringlist's sorted property could be kept un-set, and then the *protected* hack would be unnecessary as one could use the [`InsertObject`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStringList_InsertObject.html) method then.

Comment: @user - You're welcome and thank you for the kind words. :) You cannot use 'list.names[i]' with this solution because 'list[i]' f.i. is 'John' not 'John=3'.

Comment: Thank you again Sertac, I noted it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you need

```
var
    sl1, sl2: TStringList;
    sPrev: string;
    I: Integer;
begin
    sl1 := TStringList.Create;
    sl2 := TStringList.Create;
    try
        sl1.CommaText := 'mary, mary, eric, eric, john, mary, john, john,  eric, eric';
        sl1.Sorted := True;

        sPrev := '';
        for I := 0 to sl1.Count - 1 do
        begin
            if sl1[I] <> sPrev then
                sl2.Add(sl1[I]+'=1')
            else
                sl2.ValueFromIndex[sl2.Count-1] := IntToStr(StrToInt(sl2.ValueFromIndex[sl2.Count-1])+1);
            sPrev := sl1[I];
        end;

        for I := 0 to sl2.Count - 1 do
            ListView1.AddItem(sl2[I], nil);

    finally
        sl1.Free;
        sl2.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Mikael so much. I am testing your code. If the file is a big one ( containing more than 30,000 names), I feel I should have a faster search, that is why I am trying to use the binary Search function for the job. You are so kind. Can I still make modifications in the binary search so that it may work? Your above code demonstrates your great and warm-hearted help again. Thank you again.

Comment: I do not search. I just loop through one time from first item to last.

Comment: Thank you  Mikael very much. Please look at my new edition. Your first comment should also be marked as answer.